# Does hg pull only operate on the current working directory?

Tags: windows, mercurial, backup, pull

I have multiple mercurial repositories and used `hg clone` to create backups of them on our file server. Now I want to write a batch file that updates them once a day by running `hg pull -u` on each subdirectory.

I want to keep this backup script as generic as possible, so it should update all backup repositories stored in my H:\BACKUPS\REPOS folder. This is my hgbackup.bat that is stored in the same folder:

`for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad/b') do hg pull -u`

The problem: hg pull only seems to operate on the current working directory, there seems to be no switch to specify the target repository for the pull. As I hate Windows Batch Scripting, I want to keep my .bat as simple as possible and avoid cd'ing to the different directories.

Any ideas how I can run `hg pull -u` on a different directory?

Comment: If you're just storing it as a backup, why `-u`pdate on pull?  It just redundantly increases the amount of data you're storing

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the `-R`-switch:

```
hg pull -u -R /path/to/repository
```

See `hg -v help pull` for all command line options of `hg pull` (the `-v` switch tells help to include global options).

Comment: thanks for the help! Yes, I stumpled across the -R option, but I thought it would specify the repository to pull from.

Comment: Thank you!  As clarification for other googlers, the -R option is a global option to run any hg command on a directory other than the current directory.  I used it to pull changes from a commit in one repo into a related repo:  `hg log -pr 9369 -R ../other-repo | patch -p1`.  If you don't have patch, `hg import --no-commit` is similar.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and it didn't work with leading '/' char (when I used a relative path)

Answer (score 0):

Found this question quite a bit later due to a script I was working on for my own computer, and rather than a batch script, I did it in PowerShell (since you mentioned it's on a server, I assumed PS was available). This handles both Subversion and Mercurial repositories:

```
$path = "c:\users\mattgwagner\Documents\Code"

foreach($fi in get-childitem $path)
{
    if(test-path $path\$fi\.svn)
    {
        "Updating " + $fi + " via Subversion..."
        svn update $path\$fi
    }
    elseif(test-path $path\$fi\.hg)
    {
        "Updating " + $fi + " via Mercurial..."
        hg pull -u -R $path\$fi
    }
}
```